# 503 error when ajax cart order is larger then stock

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, ajax

When i try to add more products then the stock to the shopping cart with the extention ajax cart by cmsmart the page returns a 503 error. Their should be an error msg  saying the order is to large.

This is the error log thats returned:

```
here has been an error processing your request

De gevraagde hoeveelheid voor "Natural Tech Energizing Gel 150 ml" is niet beschikbaar.

Trace:
#0 /home/users/beaxmftp/beautyballoon.nl/includes/src/__default.php(10138): Mage::throwException('De gevraagde ho...')
#1 /home/users/beaxmftp/beautyballoon.nl/app/code/local/Cmsmart/AjaxCart/controllers/IndexController.php(154): Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart->addProduct('130', Array)
#2 /home/users/beaxmftp/beautyballoon.nl/app/code/local/Cmsmart/AjaxCart/controllers/IndexController.php(67): Cmsmart_AjaxCart_IndexController->tryaddAction(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), Array)
#3 /home/users/beaxmftp/beautyballoon.nl/includes/src/__default.php(14015): Cmsmart_AjaxCart_IndexController->indexAction()
#4 /home/users/beaxmftp/beautyballoon.nl/includes/src/__default.php(18432): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#5 /home/users/beaxmftp/beautyballoon.nl/includes/src/ArtsOnIT_OfflineMaintenance_Controller_Router_Standard.php(46): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#6 /home/users/beaxmftp/beautyballoon.nl/includes/src/__default.php(17962): ArtsOnIT_OfflineMaintenance_Controller_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#7 /home/users/beaxmftp/beautyballoon.nl/includes/src/__default.php(20759): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#8 /home/users/beaxmftp/beautyballoon.nl/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#9 /home/users/beaxmftp/beautyballoon.nl/index.php(89): Mage::run('', 'store')
#10 {main}
```

Can anyone help me how to resolve this?